# swiper が動作しません

Tags: javascript, swiper

LPを制作しています。

swiperを利用してスライドショーを設置しようと思っています。
ネットで調べて試してみましたが、動作しません。

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

(中略)
～</footer>

    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script>
        var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
          // 以下にオプションを設定
          loop: true,
          autoplay:{
            delay: 5000,
          },      
        });
    </script>  
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.card-slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.slider {
    width: 322px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.slider img {
    width: 100%;
}

.slider-txt {
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 196px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-txt h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slider-txt p {
    bottom: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!-- スライダーのメインコンテナの div 要素 -->
<div class="swiper-container">

<!-- ラッパー(クラス名=slider)の（スライドを囲む） div 要素 -->
  <div class="card-slider">

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（１） -->
     <div class="slider">
       <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像1">
       <div class="slider-txt">
          <h3>株式会社サンプル採用サイトのコーディングを行いました！</h3>
          <p></p>
       </div>
     </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（２） -->
     <div class="slider">
       <img src="img/arnel-hasanovic-MNd-Rka1o0Q-unsplash.png" alt="実績画像2">
       <div class="slider-txt">
         <h3>コーディングカンファレンスのイベント LPの制作を行いました！</h3>
         <p>採用技術：jQuery,WordPress<br>実装期間：4週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
       </div>
      </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（３） -->
      <div class="slider">
        <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像3">
        <div class="slider-txt">
          <h3>株式会社サンプル様採用サイトのコーデ ィングを行いました！</h3>
          <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：2週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
        </div>
       </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（４） -->
       <div class="slider">
         <img src="img/hal-gatewood-tZc3vjPCk-Q-unsplash.png" alt="実績画像4">
           <div class="slider-txt">
             <h3>株式会社サンプル様通販サイトのコーデ ィングを行いました！</h3>
             <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：6週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
           </div>
        </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（５） -->                     
        <div class="slider">
          <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像5">
             <div class="slider-txt">
                <h3>株式会社サンプル採用サイトのコーディ ングを行いました！</h3>
                <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：2週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
              </div>
          </div>

    </div><!-- ラッパー(クラス名=slider)の（スライドを囲む） div 要素 -->
   </div><!-- スライダーのメインコンテナの div 要素 -->
```

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
autoplay.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
    at autoplay.js:87
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at t.pause (autoplay.js:86)
    at t.onVisibilityChange (autoplay.js:95)
(anonymous) @ autoplay.js:87
pause @ autoplay.js:86
onVisibilityChange @ autoplay.js:95

utils.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
    at utils.js:28
    at T (utils.js:45)
    at t.getTranslate (getTranslate.js:15)
    at t.loopFix (loopFix.js:20)
    at autoplay.js:36
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

### エラー内容

エラーの内容はHTML内のクラス名が適切でないので、指定のElementが取得できず（undefined)参照エラーになっている、というものです。

### Swiperの使用方法

[Swiperの公式ドキュメント](https://swiperjs.com/get-started)はご覧になっていますか？
巷のブログを検索するよりずっと信頼性の高いドキュメントです。
基本的には、公式ドキュメントのGetting Started 通りにHTMLを実装していけば問題なく動作します。
[公式ドキュメントのHTML Layout](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#add-swiper-html-layout)はこのように記載されています。

```html
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper-container">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

ここから、実際のスライドとなる`div.swiper-slide`要素の中身を記載していくだけです。
他のタグやクラス名を変更してはいけません。（厳密には変更可能ですが、初心者向けのカスタマイズではないのでまずはテンプレート通りの実装で慣れてください）

### 補足

クラス名の付け方で察するに、slickと混同しているのではないかと思われます。
slickとswiperは全く別物です。注意してください。

以下、クラス名を適切に変更したスニペットです。スタイルも若干いじっています。

```js
var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
          // 以下にオプションを設定
          loop: true,
          autoplay:{
            delay: 5000,
          },      
        });
```

```css
.card-slider {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.swiper-slide{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #abe;
}

.slider-txt {
    padding-top: 18px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    padding-right: 17px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 196px;
    position: relative;
}

.slider-txt h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.slider-txt p {
    bottom: 30px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" />
<!-- スライダーのメインコンテナの div 要素 -->
<div class="swiper-container">

<!-- ラッパー(クラス名=slider)の（スライドを囲む） div 要素 -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（１） -->
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像1">
       <div class="slider-txt">
          <h3>株式会社サンプル採用サイトのコーディングを行いました！</h3>
          <p></p>
       </div>
     </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（２） -->
     <div class="swiper-slide">
       <img src="img/arnel-hasanovic-MNd-Rka1o0Q-unsplash.png" alt="実績画像2">
       <div class="slider-txt">
         <h3>コーディングカンファレンスのイベント LPの制作を行いました！</h3>
         <p>採用技術：jQuery,WordPress<br>実装期間：4週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
       </div>
      </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（３） -->
      <div class="swiper-slide">
        <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像3">
        <div class="slider-txt">
          <h3>株式会社サンプル様採用サイトのコーデ ィングを行いました！</h3>
          <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：2週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
        </div>
       </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（４） -->
       <div class="swiper-slide">
         <img src="img/hal-gatewood-tZc3vjPCk-Q-unsplash.png" alt="実績画像4">
           <div class="slider-txt">
             <h3>株式会社サンプル様通販サイトのコーデ ィングを行いました！</h3>
             <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：6週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
           </div>
        </div>

<!-- それぞれのスライドの div 要素（５） -->                     
        <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="img/digital-marketing-1433427_1280.png" alt="実績画像5">
             <div class="slider-txt">
                <h3>株式会社サンプル採用サイトのコーディ ングを行いました！</h3>
                <p>採用技術：jQuery,Bootstrap4<br>実装期間：2週間<br>担当コーダー：石井</p>
              </div>
          </div>

    </div><!-- ラッパー(クラス名=slider)の（スライドを囲む） div 要素 -->
   </div><!-- スライダーのメインコンテナの div 要素 -->
```